# JSON Patch - Java Implementation for an object

Tags: java, json-patch

I am new to JSON Patch and I have gone through many reference materials but I am not sure what is the best and simple approach to implement JSON Patch to an Object (JSON Model).
In my case, I am trying to implement JSON Patch to my Spring based REST API.
Can anyone have specific solution?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you mean by « implementing JSON Patch to an Object (JSON model) » but you may be interested in having a look at Java implementations of JSON-Patch such as [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) or [fge's json-patch](https://github.com/fge/json-patch).

I hope this helps.